# What is the country/region between Poland and Lithuania?

Tags: poland

What is the geographical area between Poland and Lithuania? It doesn't seem to have a name.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [Geography trivia rather than GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/is-geography-trivia-on-topic). It would be fine to ask in the GIS Chat Room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is Kaliningrad region, it is Russian territory. 
Kaliningrad (Russian: Калининград, IPA: [kəlʲɪnʲɪnˈɡrat]; former German name: Königsberg; Russian: Кёнигсберг, tr. Kyonigsberg; Old Prussian: Twangste, Kunnegsgarbs, Knigsberg) is the administrative center of Kaliningrad Oblast, a Russian exclave between Poland and Lithuania on the Baltic Sea.

In the Middle Ages, it was the site of Old Prussian settlement Twangste. In 1255, during the Northern Crusades, a new fortress was built by the Teutonic Knights. The city became the capital of the Duchy of Prussia and East Prussia (part of Germany). It was heavily damaged during World War II and its population fled or was removed by force when it became a Russian city. According to the 2010 Census, its population was 431,902. Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

It is [Kaliningrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaliningrad), a Russian enclave.